# In CSS, are fluid margins proportional to each other possible without calc()?

Tags: css

I have a textblock element with a `max-width`, and I'd like to have its left and right margins in some proportion to each other, let's say one of them half the width of the other, and to keep those proportions as the window size changes. Is this possible in older browsers that don't support `calc()` or flexbox? I suppose what I'm really asking is if it's doable with percentages?

```
    +--------+-----------+----------------+
    |        |           |                |
    | margin | textblock |     margin     |
    |        |           |                |
    |  1/2x  |           |       1x       |
    |  ←--→  |           |  ←----------→  |
    |        |           |                |
    +--------+-----------+----------------+

+------------+-----------+------------------------+
|            |           |                        |
|   margin   | textblock |         margin         |
|            |           |                        |
|    1/2x    |           |           1x           |
|  ←------→  |           |  ←------------------→  |
|            |           |                        |
+------------+-----------+------------------------+
```

Comment: we need more precision on *old browser*, it's for sure about IE, but we need to know which version because there is big difference between old IE

Comment: I guess starting with the version the supports `max-width`, which seems to be 7, according to [Can I Use...](https://caniuse.com/#search=max-width).

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate such behavior using flexbox and hidden elements where you apply different `flex-grow` in order to control how to divide the free space:

```css
.container {
 display:flex;
}
.box {
  max-width:300px;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}
.container:before {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:1;
}
.container:after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but flexbox is even less supported than calc.

Comment: @typo if it's about support you should mention it so we can know where you want this to be supported. I thought you simply don't want to use calc()

Comment: [`calc` is supported by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)... [`flexbox` is actually supported in more browsers than `calc`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)...

Comment: Temani Afif, you're right; edited. Heretic Monkey, I know major browsers support both. I'm making a simple single-page book, and I'd like it to work even on ancient browsers, because there's no reason it shouldn't on account of fancy margins.